# Could not load file or assembly Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.121.1.0

Tags: .net, database, oracle11g

I've been trying to connect to a Oracle Database using ODP 12c for .NET. I'm getting this error message when I try to connect and I can't seem to find an answer that actually works and I've searched a LOT, so, please, do not answer this question with a link to another question.

I'm using Oracle 11g Express, Windows 8.1 x64 and .NET 4.0

I'm sorry if this is a dumb question or something, but this is my first big project that actually uses a database. Do not troll it, please.

Edit: Forgot to add the error

Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.121.1.0 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Anothe Edit: I just downloaded ODAC121012Xcopy_x64, installed following the instructions for .NET 4.0 and the same problem is happening (the version has changed to 4.1.x)

Edit 3: I'm using c# and .NET, so, this isn't a web aplication.

Comment: Did you install the 64-bit version of ODP? If it was the 32-bit version you would need to enable 32-bit applications in your application pool

Comment: I searched everywhere how to do it, but I couldn't find. Where can I change that?

Comment: Looks like you have the x64 version now so forget about the app pool. It's possible the DLL did not get registered in the GAC so just try adding a reference to the DLL from visual studio. (From the Solution Explorer open your project and right click 'References' and Add Reference. Then browse to the DLL. (C:\app\YOURUSERNAME\product\12.1.x\client\odp.net\bin\4\Oracle.DataAccess.dll)

Comment: It already had the reference. Previously I also added Oracle.ManagedDataAccess in a desperate try, but nothing changed. :c

Comment: Are you running the app in IIS or IIS Express?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what "IIS" means :C I'm using oracle 11g Express (I don't think it's the same thing, but I'll add it)

Comment: It's my very first big application using database, my apologies

Comment: The path environment variable tells windows where to find dlls. If you open a command prompt window, then type "PATH", does the output contain the path to your oracle binary files? It should look something like this:  "c:\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin"

Comment: You said that you added "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" (managed .Net driver) as a reference, but the error message says that your program expects "Oracle.DataAccess" which is the native driver. Maybe the reference is wrong? Also you could try to copy the Oracle DLL manually into your bin-folder (properties of the reference -> Copy always), so that even if the DLL is not in the GAC, it can be found.

Answer (score 0):

I did something that worked for me. Go to "Options" in TOOLS menu, and go to "Projects and Solutions" then in the option "Web Projects" check the option "Use the 64 bit version of IIS Express for web sites and projects".

hope it helps!

PS: sorry by my english.